# DGET NUM error with criteria

Tags: excel-formula

DGET functions in my spreadsheet have a problem with criteria strings having the same starting characters. This is a problem. How do I resolve this?

Ex: =DGET(database, field, criterion1)

The database contains entries for criteria values of "ABC" and "ABC_123", say.
If I call DGET(database, field, "ABC"), it results in a NUM error. What do I do about this? I cannot change the spreadsheet from which the criteria values are extracted for input into the DGET function - for example I can't add columns, etc. I may be able to make some limited changes to the database entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need two changes (though due to `#NUM` error instead of `#VALUE` maybe just the first). To do an exact match with `DGET` you need to preface your criteria with `=`. So instead of `"ABC"` you would need `"=ABC"`. The final parameter of the `DGET` function does not want a single string value. As noted on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822870.aspx) page:

> You can use any range for the criteria argument, as long as it includes at least one column label and at least one cell below the column label in which you specify a condition for the column.

I think that third parameter should be a range of two cells with your criteria field name in the first cell and your criteria value `=ABC` below it. You can place this range on another worksheet if you like to stage it with the `=` as you pull it in from the other spreadsheet.

For example in my testing I am using the formula `=DGET($G$1:$I$4,"Field 3",A1:A2)` where A1 is `Field 2` and A2 is `="=ABC"` and columns headers are in G1:I1. This returns the value in column Field 3 when column Field 2 is `ABC` exactly.

DGET is touchy and not something I usually recommend so make extra sure you run key test cases when making revisions and verify this returns exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, that is how I am using it. The problem is the other spreadsheet already contains entries for ABC, ABC_123, etc. I can't easily change them to ="=ABC", ="=ABC_123",... Those values/strings are used elsewhere too and are referred to in VBA code written by others. Anyway, I spent some time trying to make this work and eventually ended up getting around it and not having to make any exact matches.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well I'm obviously working quite blind here but I'm not suggesting you change your criteria spreadsheet. I'm suggesting you create a staging tab in the spreadsheet we are pulling data into that grabs the criteria from the source spreadsheet and adds an equals sign to the front. However, if you found a viable alternative, that's great.

Comment: Oh yes - I get what you are saying now. Regardless, that will be a bit unwieldy as I am already creating cell entries that others are frowning upon - people are interested in keeping this to a minimum as this spreadsheet is already getting out of control. I know I can't paint a clearer picture, but nevermind. I removed the need for DGET to make this distinction. I was rather hoping there was some intrinsic way to look for an exact match, that was built into DGET. Thanks.

Comment: @Jabberwocky My two cents... To be honest I would probably agree with them but even more strongly. When a spreadsheet is asked to be a many sheet data management system, you are almost certainly doing something wrong. Heck just sustaining links to another Excel file usually says you're using the wrong tool. Excel IMO is for quick calculations, financial calculations, and final data rendering. When the scope gets out of hand, it's time to generate any Excel outputs from a database.